# Images breaking only on Gmail and not Ymail

Tags: html, image, email, gmail, ymail

So Gmail is breaking images. Both Ymail and Gmail change the URL of the picture but only the Gmail breaks.

**Ymail:**

[image]

```
<img src="https://ecp.yusercontent.com/mail?url=https%3A%2F%2Fpooja.qa.sharedemos.com%2Fstatic%2Fmedia%2F4213b3c0-8a62-4e61-9d1a-5cf8e6cb960b.jpeg&amp;t=1532714186&amp;ymreqid=6d717211-f81e-e822-1cd6-87000001d200&amp;sig=dezvqgVKWdTHETofpKyXyg--~C" style="width:100%;height:auto;">
```

**Gmail:**

[image]

```
<img src="https://ci5.googleusercontent.com/proxy/1xP_RDDtZXOjVhgk4KNQxeorhB3XK21eXBc8BeI6zF-SjGaE_K776PNP8PBhs0q3PxYmPUMtvyW46fFHHQQD20s0o2wwOF4u2-L84bjw_JjgXpPvkLiQjKQqgozE5QfxMP7dGqkUo9iiRMRh=s0-d-e1-ft#https://pooja.qa.sharedemos.com/static/media/4213b3c0-8a62-4e61-9d1a-5cf8e6cb960b.jpeg" style="width:100%;height:auto" class="CToWUd">
```

The images are not found (404):
[image]

Is there any way I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I checked both your Yahoo and Gmail `img` examples. Neither is a valid image.

The `img` listed in your Gmail example has two separate images listed as your image source:

```
https://ci5.googleusercontent.com/proxy/1xP_RDDtZXOjVhgk4KNQxeorhB3XK21eXBc8BeI6zF-SjGaE_K776PNP8PBhs0q3PxYmPUMtvyW46fFHHQQD20s0o2wwOF4u2-L84bjw_JjgXpPvkLiQjKQqgozE5QfxMP7dGqkUo9iiRMRh=s0-d-e1-ft#
```

and:

```
https://pooja.qa.sharedemos.com/static/media/4213b3c0-8a62-4e61-9d1a-5cf8e6cb960b.jpeg
```

Google states that the first url is invalid, just like your example states.

The second one raises security concerns in two different web browsers.

I'd suggest testing your image urls and make sure they are on a server with a valid security certificate or they will never work for email clients.

Good luck.